# Pyspark driver is not picking up my env configurations

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-connect

I am on a windows machine. Running pyspark that was set up using databricks cli.

Getting this error:

```
Python in worker has different version 3.8 than that in driver 3.9, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions. Please check environment variables PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON are correctly set.
```

It says pyspark driver is 3.9, but my PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON is pointing to a 3.8 version of python.

[PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON points to 3.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25EWh.png)

Why is my pyspark driver still running 3.9?

Thank you.